# Add method in same class or in String class - Best practices

Tags: ruby, string, class, overriding

I want define a new method to validate a string like this:

```
# lib/rips/variables/variable.rb

class Variable
  # Check if value is a valid number (...,-1,0,1...)
  def number? (value)
    /\A[-]?\d+\z/ === value
  end
end
```

And it invokes like this in the same class and derived classes:

```
# lib/rips/variables/inmediate.rb

class Inmediate < Variable
  # value = "+42" -> return false
  def valid_syntax? (value)
    number?(value)
  end
end
```

But other way to do this it's adding method `number?` to String class:

```
# lib/rips/utils/string.rb

class String
  # Check if value is a valid number (...,-1,0,1...)
  def number?
    /\A[-]?\d+\z/ === self
  end
end
```

And now it invokes like this:

```
# lib/rips/variables/inmediate.rb
require "lib/rips/utils/string"

class Inmediate < Variable
  # value = "+42" -> return false
  def valid_syntax? (value)
    value.number?
  end
end
```

So I have `number?(value)` if I declare method in same class or `value.number?` if I add method to String class. Isn't only method, I want to add more new methods too. I prefer second way but I don't know if the best practice in this case.

Which is the best practice?

Comment: There's no need to put the hyphen in a character class. Also, if your regex is `r`, it might be clearer to write `match r` or `self =~ r`. Lastly, `integer?` would be a more suitable name for the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is use [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) (by link described why and how to use it functionality). It is available since ruby 2.0.

Comment: I like it, I did not know about `Refinements` but I need compatibility with 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option, where you get the convenience of calling your custom methods directly on the `String object,` but without adding it to the `String class`.

```
module StringExtensions
  def number?
    /\A[-]?\d+\z/ === self
  end
end

string = "1"

string.number? # => NoMethodError: undefined method `number?' for "1":String

string.extend(StringExtensions)
string.number? # => true

"2".number? # => NoMethodError: undefined method `number?' for "1":String
```